# Applescript to quit all active browsers on Mac?

Tags: applescript

am trying to quit all the active browsers using the below code, but am unable to get the list of all active browsers to quit, i tried below code...pls suggest..

```
tell application "System Events"

    set appList to every process whose visible is true

    repeat with thisApp in appList
        tell process browser
            quit
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't quit a "process", only an "application". Also, you will have to finish the browserList for all possible browser names.

```
set browserList to {"Safari", "Firefox"}

tell application "System Events"
    set appList to name of every process whose visible is true
end tell

repeat with i from 1 to count of appList
    set thisApp to item i of appList
    if thisApp is in browserList then
        tell application thisApp to quit
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the reply.. is their any other way to get the browser list on run time, instead of mentioning explicitly??

Comment: I thought about that. I made a tool to list all the applications that can open a file (http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/AllApplications/AllApplications.html) and ran an html file through it. It returns much more than browsers, things like Excel also turn up in that list. So I don't think you can get a list of just "browsers".

Comment: k thanku so much.. i will download the same tool and for any concerns will come back..